# Get the option caption to json object using knockout js

Tags: json, knockout.js

Here I want to get the Option Text to the json object using knockout js

[example Code](http://jsfiddle.net/uderox/uWyM9/)
html

```
<select name="VehicleType" id="vehicleTypeDropdown" data-bind="value: VehicleType">
    <option value="New" selected="selected">Aluth</option>
    <option value="Used">Parana</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="Mileage" data-bind="disable: VehicleType() === 'New',value: Mileage" class="input-large">
<hr/>

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

js

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.VehicleType = ko.observable();
    this.Mileage = ko.observable();
    this.optionText = ko.observable();

    this.VehicleType.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        if (newValue === "New") {
            this.Mileage(0);
        }
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

How populate optionText using drop down caption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same in more observable style

Html

```
<select data-bind="options: vehicleTypes, optionsText: 'Name', value: selectedVehicle">
</select>

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

JavaScript

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var Vehicle = function(name, type) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Type = type;
    }; 
    this.vehicleTypes = ko.observableArray([
            new Vehicle("Aluth", "New"),
            new Vehicle("parana", "Used")
        ]);
    this.selectedVehicle = ko.observable();

    this.selectedVehicle.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        alert(newValue.Name);
        alert(newValue.Type);
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Here is full version: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZgfX8/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Add an empty-value option to the list:

```
<option value="">- Select -</option>
```

Updated here: http://jsfiddle.net/uWyM9/1/

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

**UPDATE:**

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but maybe you mean you need to bind to a dynamic array?
http://jsfiddle.net/uWyM9/2/

Can you elaborate more please?

Comment: NO, I want to bind Option Text to the object here , "Aluth" and "Parana" text should be bind with object